# Flask Bcrypt TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a cdata pointer, not NoneType

Tags: encryption, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, salt, bcrypt

Encountered this bug.  Being an amateur coder I'm really struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

File "C:\Users.virtualenvs\flask\lib\site-packages\bcrypt__init__.py", line 63, in hashpw
retval = _bcrypt.lib.crypt_rn(password, salt, hashed, len(hashed))
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a cdata pointer, not NoneType

Models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic',
                            primaryjoin="User.id==Post.user_id")
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    followed = db.relationship('User',
                                secondary=followers,
                                primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
                                secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
                                backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
                                lazy='dynamic')

    #reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='author', lazy='dynamic') This is the review connectino for the user. 
    @hybrid_property
    def password_hash(self):
        return self.password

    @password_hash.setter
    def set_password(self, plaintext):
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plaintext)

    def is_correct_password(self, plaintext):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password, plaintext)
```

Views.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=form.nickname.data).first_or_404()
        if user.is_correct_password(form.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            flash("you've been logged in!, 'success'")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            flash('your email or password doesnt match!', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('login.html',
                            title='Sign In',
                            form=form)
```

Comment: it seems like the user's password is None

Comment: Definitely confident I had typed in my password that I had setup.  Is there anything else that may be causing this?

Comment: Just tried registering and then logging in with the above code.  100 set a proper password in the db, but still throwing this error.  So somewhere the password is being set to None?  Can anything think of what the issue might be?